# mysql update rows in an inner joined table

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I am trying to update a large amount of rows in bulk in on a mysql server through c#.

I know that one can replace in bulk using the syntax

```
INSERT INTO table.items(`id`, `asset_id`, `bot_steam64`)
VALUES(...),
      (...),
      (...),
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE asset_id=...
```

I want to do this operation on a portion of my table that

1. shares the a field value with another table I have
2. matches a specific field value in the other table   (this sounds like a join)

I do not know how to express the compound logic im describing or if there's another way to go about it

```
items:
asset_id bigint(32) UN 
trade_id bigint(32) UN 
value int(11) 
name tinytext 
bot_steam64 bigint(20) 
winner tinyint(4) 
id bigint(32) UN PK

bets:
trade_id bigint(32) UN 
user_steam64 bigint(20) UN PK 
match_id bigint(32) UN PK 
total_value bigint(32) UN 
chosen_team tinyint(3) UN
```

Specifically, `items.trade_id=bets.trade_id` and `match_id=1234`.

Comment: inserting into the same table you're selecting from? instead of flailing around trying to get this query working, why not just run a bunch of separate `update` queries?

Comment: because i dont want to wait 5 minutes

Comment: Can you please explain in words what you want to achieve? The query syntax is incorrect and not sufficiently explanatory.

Comment: i misread thoughts from a different SO thread, ill update in a second

Comment: i need to incorporate the phrase `flailing around` more here

Comment: Dunno about others but I still don't have a clue about what OP is trying to do.

Comment: I'm getting there. Please share the table structures as well and also indicate the relations between columns (which table.column matches what table2.column2).

Comment: Also indicate the rules based on which the insert should happen. You are asking for a specific solution, you need to provide all the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table t1
(
    i int not null,
    some_other_thing int not null
);

create table t2
(   i int not null,
    updateMe int not null,
    some_other_thing int not null
);

insert into  t1(i,some_other_thing) values (1,1),(2,7);
insert into  t2(i,updateMe,some_other_thing) values (1,0,0),(2,0,4);

update t2
join t1
on t2.i=t1.i and t2.some_other_thing=4
set t2.updateMe=9;

-- 1 row changed

select * from t2
```

tweak as necessary if you need to mess around with t1.some_other_thing in join.

The reason I am not doing `insert on duplicate update` is because you said you wanted to do an update at the beginning. And you said **portion of the table that ...**

Comment: I ended up going this route. I hadn't used transactions before, which made it not clear to do so initially

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO table.items(`id`, `asset_id`, `bot_steam64`)
    SELECT t.*
    FROM (SELECT ... UNION ALL
          SELECT ... UNIONALL
          . . .
         ) t
    WHERE t.col IN (SELECT a.anothercol FROM anothertable a)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE asset_id = ...;
```